# Getting error "'datepicker._defaults' is null or not an object" in extend method of timepicker.js

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am using Jquery datetimepicker(js/timepicker.js)
and getting error "datepicker._defaults' is null or not an object" in extend method of following javascript file

Error comes when loading timepicker.js file.'datepicker' object  is undefined in javascript file.

```
===================timepicker.js===============
    /**
     * Extending default values
     */
    $.extend($.datepicker._defaults, {
        'stepMinutes': 1, // Number of minutes to step up/down
        'stepHours': 1, // Number of hours to step up/down
        'time24h': false, // True if 24h time
        'showTime': false, // Show timepicker with datepicker
        'altTimeField': '' // Selector for an alternate field to store time into
    });
```

Comment: What about the headline (===================timepicker.js===============)? Is it part of your js file? If so, you should use a valid comments (`// Oneline JS Code`, `/* Multi Line JS code */`) e.g. `/*===================timepicker.js===============*/` or `//===================timepicker.js===============`

Comment: No it is not part of js file. I just used to separate name of js file.I am facing literally error related to "datepicker._defaults' is null or not an object"  and datepicker object is null in timepicker.js file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to include first "jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js" after that include  "timepicker.js" file